# Why cannot find `when` form when I use neil/sicp?

Tags: if-statement, scheme, racket, sicp

I was solving exercise-3.23 of [section 3.3.2 of SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%_sec_3.3.2),
which is an implementation of deque.

As Racket doesn't support `set-car!` and `set-cdr!`，so I use `#lang planet neil/sicp` from [SICP Support for DrRacket](http://www.neilvandyke.org/racket-sicp/)，and wrote the code:

```
#lang planet neil/sicp

(define (make-deque) (cons '() '()))
(define (empty-deque? dq) (null? (front-ptr dq)))
;;; just here, I use when form
(define (front-delete-deque! dq)
  (cond ((empty-deque? dq)
         (error "FRONT-DELETE-DEQUE! called with empty deque" dq))
        (else
         (set-car! dq (caddr (front-ptr dq)))
         (when (null? (front-ptr dq))
           (set-cdr! dq '())))))
(define (front-ptr dq) (car dq))
(define (rear-ptr dq) (cdr dq))
```

I got an error: `when: unbound identifier in module`, which is very strange.

I think it has something to do with the `neil/sicp`, since Racket has `when` form.

And can someone explain what exactly `#lang planet neil/sicp` means and matters?

PS: forget how I implement the deque.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite possible that the implementors of the `neil/sicp` package chose not to support `when` - after all, it's not part of the [standard](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs.html) language and (as far as I can remember) it was never mentioned in [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-38.html). But fear not, `when` is not essential and you can write something equivalent, just substitute this part:

```
(when (null? (front-ptr dq))
  (set-cdr! dq '()))
```

With this:

```
(if (null? (front-ptr dq))
  (set-cdr! dq '())
  #f)
```

And if you're feeling bold you can even write your own `when` macro, one of the nice things of Scheme is that you can extend its syntax. Left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It's a good alternative. But I want to know what`neil/scip` have done, and why it doesn't define `when` since it's a support for sicp.

Comment: @WindorC `when` is not part of the [standard](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs.html) Scheme language, the implementors of the package simply chose not to support it. It's not essential, it's just syntactic sugar for `(if <condition> (begin <expressions>) (void))`. In fact, as far as I remember `when` is never  [mentioned](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-38.html) in SICP, so what would be the point of adding it to the package?

Comment: @WindorC just to be clear: Racket and Scheme are different languages; SICP, and by extension the `neil/sicp` package, deal with Scheme - so you can't expect the package to support all syntactic forms from Racket

Comment: Thanks for explanation, I know the two are different, but I do not know Racket has gone so far. Maybe it's not a good choice for learning sicp, or I miss something when using Racket? By the way, `void` also comes to a `unbound identifier in module`.

Comment: @WindorC Racket is a fine choice for going through SICP, as long as you use one of the support packages and stick to the book, avoiding forms which are not used in the book. If `(void)` doesn't work, replace it with `#f`, it's just a way to say: "ignore the return value". And feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) this answer if it was helpful for you ;)

Comment: It helps a lot. I have changed my code structure to avoid the `when`(or `if`).

Answer (score 0):

SICP is beautiful stuff; beautifully designed to work with Scheme, plain and simple.  Rather than dealing with the idiosyncrasies of Racket, such as not having `set-car!` apparently, why not just choose a proper Scheme?

There are different Scheme standards.  The most recent, R7RS, defines `when` and provides a definition as:

```
(define-syntax when
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((when test result1 result2 ...)
     (if test
         (begin result1 result2 ...)))))
```

If you use a Scheme based on R5RS or R6RS they will either already define `when` or allow you to define it as above.